# Java Why is my resulting image always flipped and rotated?

Tags: java, image-processing

I'm trying to access each pixel, manipulate it then save it back to the system. But the resulting image is always flipped and rotated, why is this? 
Here is my code for input:

```
 BufferedImage input_image=ImageIO.read(new File("F:\\sophie4.png"));
 int result[][] = convertTo2DWithoutUsingGetRGB(input_image);

 private static int[][] convertTo2DWithoutUsingGetRGB(BufferedImage image) {

      final byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
      final int width = image.getWidth();
      final int height = image.getHeight();
      final boolean hasAlphaChannel = image.getAlphaRaster() != null;

      int[][] result = new int[height][width];
      if (hasAlphaChannel) {
         final int pixelLength = 4;
         for (int pixel = 0, row = 0, col = 0; pixel < pixels.length; pixel += pixelLength) {
            int argb = 0;
            argb += (((int) pixels[pixel] & 0xff) << 24); // alpha
            argb += ((int) pixels[pixel + 1] & 0xff); // blue
            argb += (((int) pixels[pixel + 2] & 0xff) << 8); // green
            argb += (((int) pixels[pixel + 3] & 0xff) << 16); // red
            result[row][col] = argb;
            col++;
            if (col == width) {
               col = 0;
               row++;
            }
         }
      } else {
         final int pixelLength = 3;
         for (int pixel = 0, row = 0, col = 0; pixel < pixels.length; pixel += pixelLength) {
            int argb = 0;
            argb += -16777216; // 255 alpha
            argb += ((int) pixels[pixel] & 0xff); // blue
            argb += (((int) pixels[pixel + 1] & 0xff) << 8); // green
            argb += (((int) pixels[pixel + 2] & 0xff) << 16); // red
            result[row][col] = argb;
            col++;
            if (col == width) {
               col = 0;
               row++;
            }
         }
      }

      return result;
   }
```

That works, i get the pixels, but even without processing the pixels, if i output the image, its always flipped.. Here is my output code:

```
 BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(result.length, result[0].length, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    for (int row = 0; row  < result.length; row ++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < result[row].length; col++) {
            image.setRGB(row, col, result[row][col]);
        }
    }

File ImageFile = new File("path");
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", ImageFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You can see the input and output image below
[image: OutputImage]

[image: Input Image]

Comment: You're processing the image using `result[row][col] = argb;` but writing using `image.setRGB(x, y, result[x][y]);`, which seems backwards

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have replaced x & y with row & col.. See the code now, still doesn't work though. Unless there's something i'm not getting straight. If i exchange the two I get an ArrayOutOfBoundException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting confused (or at least I am), because you're resulting array is height by width (not width x height which makes more sense to me), so, instead of...

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(result.length, result[0].length, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

it should be...

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(result[0].length, result.length, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

and

```
image.setRGB(row, col, result[row][col]);
```

should be

```
image.setRGB(col, row, result[row][col]); // See why that's consfusing
```